# how to correctly cast uint32_t to unsigned

Tags: c++, c++11, ubsan, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to fix some C++ code with address sanitizer.
The code says:

```
unsigned result = *(uint32_t*)data;
```

And the sanitizer gives:

```
runtime error: load of misaligned address 0x6280033f410a for type 'uint32_t', which requires 4 byte alignment
```

How do I need to fix this?

Comment: `memcpy` the pointer to a real `uint32_t`, before casting it to `unsigned`.

Comment: Why are you using that cast?

Comment: What type is `data`?

Comment: The question is apparently not about "how to cast". And it seems to have nothing to do with "cast to `unsigned`". The question is rather about how to read misaligned data. So, please confirm: do you really intend to read misaligned data? Is it supposed to be misaligned? Why is it misaligned and how did it end up that way?

Comment: I suspect the title does not match the actual requirement

Comment: Without any feedback from OP this question isn't very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> load of misaligned address 0x6280033f410a for type 'uint32_t' ...
> ```
>
> How do I need to fix this?

You need to create an aligned object (such as a variable), and copy the content from the misaligned address:

```
std::uint32_t u32;
std::memcpy(&u32, data, sizeof u32);
```

This assumes that you intend to read `sizeof u32` bytes from that address and that those bytes are ordered in native endianness.

> how to correctly cast uint32_t to unsigned

Implicit conversion should be just fine:

```
unsigned result = u32;
```

Comment: many thanks, `std::uint32_t u32; std::memcpy(&u32, data, sizeof u32);` fixed the issue!